# Include or exclude where clause in Linq to Sql c# function

Tags: c#, sql, linq

the issue is I have UI which user can select location and job but they might select All in both of the drop down, which linq below should ignores the where clause if the value of `emplId = 0` and same for jobId,
i know how to do this using normal if EmplId = 0 then do //stuff, but i was wondring if there is an cleaner way of doing this.

```
public IEnumerable<employees> GetByEmployeIdAndJobId(int EmpId, int JobId)
{
    if (EmplId > 0 && JobId > 0){
    var employees= (from e in Table.Employees
                   where e.employeeId == EmplId && e.JobId == JobId
                   select e).ToList()
    }

    else
    {     var employees= (from e in Table.Employees
                   select e).ToList()
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI : if user select All in Employee dropdown the value is 0

Comment: code under if and else is exactly same ???

Comment: sorry updated it now

Comment: check the answer by VC 74

Answer (score 2):

I  guess your else part does not contain the where clause:

```
IEnumerable<employees> employees = Table.employees;
if (EmplId > 0 && JobId > 0)
{
  employees = employees.Where(e => (e.employeeId == EmplId && e.JobId == JobId));
}

employees = employees.ToList();
```

and to handle EmpID and JobId separately:

```
IEnumerable<employees> employees = Table.employees;

if (EmplId > 0)
{
  employees = employees.Where(e => (e.employeeId == EmplId));
}

if (JobId > 0)
{
  employees = employees.Where(e => (e.JobId == JobId));
}

employees = employees.ToList();
```

Comment: what happens if employee id = 0 and job id is 2 do i have to create another else if ?, it will look very messy, practically it will be 4 different options.

Comment: @DisplayName Your initial code did not handle that case. I'll update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build a predicate that will handle all the scenarios that user can select, something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetByEmployeIdAndJobId(int empId, int jobId)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Employee>();
    if(empId > 0)
        predicate = predicate.And(e => e.EmployeeId == empId);
    if(jobId > 0)
        predicate = predicate.And(e => e.JobId == jobId);
    return Table.Employees.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: If JobId and EmpId is 0 then what happen in your code?

Comment: It will return all employees.